# Need help with padding property of CSS

Tags: css

Enter Text:

```
<span style="padding-right: 5px margin-left: 40px;"> 
    <asp:TextBox 
        class="tbox" 
        ID="txt" 
        runat="server" 
        MaxLength="256" 
        Style="width: 200px;">
    </asp:TextBox>
</span>
```

This padding property just won't work. I want space between "Enter Text:" and my text box. Why is it not working? I don't want to give spaces using `nbsp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a semi colon after 5px

It should read

```
<span style="padding-right: 5px; margin-left: 40px;">
```